# How to open chrome aggregated time?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Like this picture,I can not find the feature.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the summary tab under the performance tab [image: Picture of the tab]

Comment: What does range mean?

Comment: I don't know. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) doesn't say anything about it.